# R plot, changing element on axis

Tags: r

[image]

In R plot,

I cannot think of the name for the element I want to change in the above chart, and which parameter controls that?

Thanks.

Comment: Those are axis ticks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to plot tickmarks outside graph use argument `tck=` and give negative number.

```
plot(1:10,tck=-0.05)
```

If you need to plot tickmarks inside graph then give positive number to `tck=`

```
plot(1:10,tck=0.05)
```